# Bootstrap drive for 2-transistor forward converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I need a driver for the high side switch in a 2 transistor forward converter as follows:

[image: principle]

First, I thought a bootstrap circuit would be fine because during the freewheeling phase, the highside FET's source is slightly below 0 volts, so a bootstrap capacitor could easily be charged. And during startup, I turn on the lowside FET only, so the bootstrap cap can be charged.

However, this turned out to be not reliable enough. I think the reason is that the primary inductance of the transformer is too high, so there is not enough time to charge the bootstrap cap.

Is there a solution for the problem?
Almost for sure it will not be possible to use an IC because the DC voltage is way beyond 600V, which is the usual range of those integrated low and highside drivers.

I found out it works reliably as soon as it has been able to switch a few times, this is indeed due to the highside source being pulled towards ground during freewheeling. But the startup is the problem.

Comment: Why is it a problem at start up if it only takes a few cycles. What might go wrong over this short period?

Comment: due to the primary inductance, there is not enough current flowing to charge the bootstrap capacitor, I guess.

Comment: No, I didn't ask what caused this to happen I asked what problem it causes as a result of inadequate bootstrapping for a few cycles.

Comment: There is a 1200 volt version of the IC you described, or you could try looking at using a pulse transformer.  There are plenty of good app notes out there.  We use this approach on our high voltage drives at high temperatures because the high-side drivers don't survive.